# how to run an http online radio with omxplayer in background?

Tags: bash, omxplayer

I use omxplayer to stream a internet radio, but omxplayer is printing a whole lot of stats on the terminal, i want it fully in background.
i tried redirecting the stdout and stderr with `&> /dev/null &`
but no luck.
here is the bash commands i run:

```
wget -O tmp.fifo http://url/stream.mp3 &> /dev/null &
omxplayer -o local tmp.fifo &> /dev/null &
```

Comment: You should clarify the context here.  Presumably you aren't using a GUI desktop, because you could simply minimize the terminal window and use another one.

Comment: i actually do use a GUI desktop, but i wont in my final result, i want to keep one terminal open at all time. There is no way of completely hiding all those stats ?

Comment: Try `omxplayer whatevercommandgoeshere > /dev/null`. This works for me.

Comment: tried it, ddnt work, i think the issue is with the wget, i edited the question.

Comment: Did you try `wget -b`

Comment: Explain what the final context is then.  I may have a suggestion, but I hate wasting time typing these out only to get, "Oh that won't work I'm using SSH..."  See also the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479).

Comment: In the end i will be controlling the Pi with an android app by bluetooth, so i wanted to keep the pi as clean as possible during runtime, so i can run other commands, i need the terminal to be accessible.

Comment: now i get `Continuing in background, pid 1525.
Output will be written to ‘wget-log.1’.
Audio codec mp3 channels 2 samplerate 44100 bitspersample 16
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
`  but at least the terminal is now accessible, so i can run other commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding -b after the wget, but now a log file is added every time i run the script. So that's a new issue to solve.

[Update]: Solved the log file issue by adding -q to the wget. Also running the script with `&> /dev/null &`

here is the complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall omxplayer.bin
wget -b -q -O radio.fifo http://url/stream.mp3 &> /dev/null & 
omxplayer -o local radio.fifo
```

And run it like this: `sh script.sh &> /dev/null &`, and all is good now.

Comment: Does not work properly. Music repeats and then stops

Answer (score 1):

The modified script below works for me ...

-g create as log file omxplayer.log ... watch that it's size increases overtime that's why /tmp /is used to remove it on each reboot

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://www1.wdr.de/unternehmen/der-wdr/empfang-technik/webradio-100.html
cd /tmp
url=https://wdr-wdr2-rheinland.icecastssl.wdr.de/wdr/wdr2/rheinland/mp3/128/stream.mp3
pgrep omxplayer
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "killing running omxplayer ..."
  pkill -9 omxplayer
fi
nohup omxplayer -g -o local $url &
```